# Sort including ratio between values and best of list

Tags: ratio, sorting

I have following values for each object:

1. 100,50,50
2. 30,100,20
3. 100,80,20
4. 120,50,70
5. 120,60,60
6. 300,100,20
7. 350,50,100
8. 30,300,300
9. 120,10,100

I want to find an function how to calculate optimal ratio (which should be 2:1:1) and compare that ratio also with first value, so from my list best option should be option 5, then 4, then maybe 1, ...

So aspect ratio is crutial, first value should be 2*(second,third) while second and thirdone should be equal ideally. If they are not equal and difference is huge, then it should be. "penaltized" ...

Dont know if I explain it correctly. This should be applied in bigdata for future, where I want to always find best value, if it is possible

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to meet your criteria. You have to think a little more deeply about what you want your function to do, if you want to get a useful answer to your question.

Comment: I think I explained what should be result, and which criteria are important, am I missing something?

Comment: What you've written is not enough to tell me which of $100,50,40$ and $100,40,40$  and $100,50,30$ and $100,30,30$ is best. Where does $100,60,50$ fit in? or $100,60,40$? Until we know precisely how you are going to rank, any formula we might give is pure guesswork. Even you say *maybe* number $1$ is the third best. If you can't tell for sure, then you haven't thought through what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I understand, well I know, that for my system functionality best is when those three parameters are in ratio 2:1:1 ... and also larger value wins ... so if there is 100:50:50 and then 300:150:150, secondone is definetely better ... on the other hand, first attribute is most important, but if it has too bad  ratio, for example 500:10:10, then 300:150:150 is better also maybe 100:50:50 ... I know it is vague, but this I want to find some "close" solution, I know that exact solution which will be always 100% correct I cannot exlain, this is why Iˇm asking :)